# How to crop rect area of PDF page using pdf.js

Tags: pdf, crop, pdf.js

I want to crop specific rect `(x,y,width,height)` of a PDF page. Is that possible with pdf.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the canvas reference of the page. Let us say your current scale is 133% so you need to multiply your coordinates by 1.33

```
var context = document.getElementById("page1").getContext('2d');

var imageData = context.getImageData(
   160.89*(1.33),
   193.97*(1.33),
   517.29*(1.33),
   148.87*(1.33))
```

Then you can put it to some other canvas or do something with it

```
context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
```

Comment: This answer has no relation to pdf.js.

Comment: Also cropping this way might crop lines in the pages, which I don't think is feasible.